# Autocomplete key UP/DOWN behaviour

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I am using jQuery's autocomplete plugin. I have modified this to support multiple selection from the result menu with the help of checkbox. For me, **the value in autocomplete box should only be updated when user clicks on checkbox alone.**

1. When mouse is hovered over the result menu, the value in autocomplete textbox is not getting updated. - Default behaviour.
2. When the search result is navigated using key UP/DOWN, the corresponding row's (one which is focused) value is getting updated. I have overcome this by returning false from focus function.
3. **The problematic situation** - user has selected a row using mouse, then the corresponding value of row is updated in the autocomplete's textbox. After this user navigates the results using key UP/DOWN, the value in autocomplete textbox is getting replaced by the value of the row which is currently in focus using key UP/DOWN.

[I have uploaded an image explaining the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKbix.png)

In the image the row highlighted in "red" represents the one which was selected using mouse and the one highlighted in "Yellow" is the current row in focus as a result of key DOWN.

Do let me know how, to achieve this.

```
 $("#name")
.keydown(function(event) 
{
        //code for highlighting
    } 
 ).autocomplete({
    minLength: 2,
    multiple: true,
    source: function(request,response)
    {
        //fetch required data, format: [{name:" ", id: " "},{name:" ", id: " "}]
    },
    select: function(event,ui)
    {
        var terms = split( this.value );
        terms.pop();
        terms.push( ui.item.value);
        terms.push( "" );
        this.value = terms.join( " ," );
        return false;
    },
    focus: function(event,ui)
    {
       return false;
    }
 }).data("autocomplete")._renderMenu = function(menuUI,items)
 {
    //change the rendering to display checkbox for each result.
    //on clicking on the checkbox, its value will be appended to autocomplete's textbox
 };
 });
```

Comment: Have you checked the way they implemented multiple selection on the [demo page](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#multiple) of the plugin ? They provide a custom `select` event handler.

Comment: yes, i have implemented the same way. but that's for supporting multiple searches. my impl: will work the same way. the only difference is with single search you can select multiple values.

Comment: Well, not seeing your code makes it a bit difficult to help. But you could still overwrite the select event, check the box of the selected item and loop through all the checkbox to build the value of selected boxes.

Comment: for your convince i am copying the select code here

select: function(event, ui) 
{
    var terms = split(this.value);
    // remove the current input
    terms.pop();
    // add the selected item
    terms.push(ui.item.value);
   // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at end
    terms.push("");
    this.value = terms.join(" ,");
    return false;
 }

Comment: Would be easier if you post your code for creating the autocomplete as an edit to your question.